# Django -Python Copyfile using win32api permission denied

Tags: django

I was looking to implement a copy on the server where I click a button on the client-side HTML of my webserver and the server implements a copy of a particular file inside the server from a fixed destination to another destination inside the server itself. The server is windows based so I was using the win32api CopyFile method but it shows an access denied error. How can I resolve this issue? I have tried setting permissions for the drive. It seems as if Django needs administrative privileges for this but not sure. Other solutions are welcome.

Comment: It worked using shutil.copy method but not sure why the win32api didn't work